# reload Data table with ajax.url().load() not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a server-side paging enabled data table that works fine. Following is my table initialized, which pulls json data & renders:

```
function initTestTable(){
    myTable = $('#testTable').dataTable({
   "processing": true,
   "serverSide": true,
   "ajax": {
       "url": "testTableData.html",
       "type": "GET",
   },
   "columnDefs": [ {
       "targets": 0,
       "data": "code",
       "render": function ( data, type, full ) {
           return '<a href="'+data+'">'+data+'</a>';
         }
     },
     {
       "targets": 1,
       "data": "description",
       "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
           return data;
       }
     }]
 });
```

}

Even ajax following ajax reload working fine:

```
myTable.api().ajax.reload(); //reloads ajax with very previous ajaxed URL
```

The problem is when I want to relaod with different URL using following load() function. Actually it is freezing the on "Processing..." message without rendering the data on table. Response seems to alright.

```
myTable.api().ajax.url('getNextData.html').load(); //reloads ajax with specified URL
```

I dont know what is going wrong as there are errors are shown in the developer tool console. Please suggest.

Comment: Why you are not using **fnDraw();**.

Comment: @Bugfixer - No need to use fnDraw(); realoding ajax itself shall render.

Comment: The only reason for this not to work is that either getNextData.html not exists, not are readable or return errorneous JSON.